# Java volatile memory ordering and its compilation on x86-64

Tags: java, x86-64, volatile, memory-barriers, java-memory-model

Consider the following simple Java application:

```
public class Main {
    public int a;
    public volatile int b;

    public void thread1(){
        int b;
        a = 1;
        b = this.b;
    }

    public void thread2(){
        int a;
        b = 1;
        a = this.a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main m = new Main();
        while(true){
            m.a = 0;
            m.b = 0;
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> m.thread1());
            Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> m.thread2());
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:** Is it possible that reading into local variables will result in `thread1::b = 0` and `thread2::a = 0`?

I could not prove that it could not happen from the JMM standpoint so I went down to analyzing compiled code for `x86-64`.

Here is what compiler ends up with for methods `thread1` and `thread2` (code unrelated to the while loop and some comments generated by `-XX:+PrintAssembly` omitted for simplicity):

`thread1`:

```
  0x00007fb030dca235: movl    $0x1,0xc(%rsi)    ;*putfield a
  0x00007fb030dca23c: mov     0x10(%rsi),%esi   ;*getfield b
```

`thread2`:

```
  0x00007fb030dcc1b4: mov     $0x1,%edi
  0x00007fb030dcc1b9: mov     %edi,0x10(%rsi)
  0x00007fb030dcc1bc: lock addl $0x0,0xffffffffffffffc0(%rsp) ;*putfield b 
  0x00007fb030dcc1c2: mov     0xc(%rsi),%esi    ;*getfield a
```

So what we have here is that `volatile` read is done for free, `volatile` write requires `mfence` (or `lock add`) after.

So `thread1`'s Store can still be forwarded after the Load and therefore `thread1::b = 0` and `thread2::a = 0` is possible.

Comment: It's somewhat confusing to have an `int a;` in `thread2` that shadows the `public int a;` class member.  Same for `int b` in thread1. What's up with that?

Comment: @PeterCordes That's just a naming of local variables. It can be changed to any other names.

Comment: This question might be easier to understand if you added some `System.out.println(...)` statements, and then asked about what output is possible or not possible.

Comment: Normal examples and reordering litmus tests pick different names, often `r0` and `r1` for "registers" to talk about load results that threads observed.

Comment: What do you mean by saying a store can be "forwarded"?  Neither thread reloads its own store, so there's no store-to-load forwarding.  Perhaps you meant "reordered after"?  Yes, StoreLoad reordering is the only kind allowed on x86 (other than the interesting effects created by store-forwarding); x86's memory model is basically program-order + a store buffer with store-to-load forwarding.

Comment: @PeterCordes It was meant that `thread1`'s Store `a = 1` can be reordered with Load `b = this.b` since there's no any fences in between.

Comment: @SolomonSlow After almost 30 minutes of running the example it's showed up.

Comment: Yeah, your analysis looks right.  StoreLoad reordering of `a=1` with `b=this.b` allows an effective order of `b=this.b` ; `b=1` ; `a=this.a` ; `a=1` for example.  (Using your inconvenient names where `b` is sometimes a local, sometimes the shared variable).

Comment: Are you asking if it's permissible under the JMM or if it could actually happen? The JMM only guarantees that a `volatile` write *happens-before* subsequent reads of the same variable. It wouldn't have any effect on your code because nothing happens before the write or after the read.

Comment: @shmosel Yeah, was interesting regarding if it's required from JMM/and actual behavior of the compiler to declare both variables `volatile` to prevent `thead1:a = 0` and `thread2:b = 0`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Probably the example was crafted not in the best way so it took pretty long time to catch the reordering...

Comment: @SomeName, I don't understand. _What_ showed up after almost 30 minutes? The program in your example produces no output. Did you set a breakpoint somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, your analysis looks right.  This is the StoreLoad litmus test with only *one* of the sides having a StoreLoad barrier (like C++ `std::atomic` iwth `memory_order_seq_cst`, or Java `volatile`).  It's needed in both to shut down this possibility. See Jeff Preshing's [Memory Reordering Caught in the Act](https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/) for details on the case where neither side has such a barrier.

StoreLoad reordering of `a=1` with `b=this.b` allows an effective order of

```
   thread1        thread2
                  b=this.b        // reads 0
    b=1
    a=this.a                      // reads 0
                  a=1
```

(This mess of names is why it's normal for examples and reordering litmus tests to pick names like `r0` and `r1` for "registers" to talk about load results that threads observed, definitely not the same names as the shared variables which make the meaning of a statement context-sensitive and a pain to look at and think about in a reordering diagram.)

> So thread1's Store can still be **forwarded** after the Load and therefore `thread1::b = 0` and `thread2::a = 0` is possible.

It seems you mean "reordered after", not forwarded.  "Forwarding" in a memory-ordering context would mean store-to-load forwarding (where a load pulls data from the store buffer before it becomes globally visible, so it sees its own stores right away, in a different order relative to other things than other threads would).  But neither of your threads is reloading its own stores, so that's not happening.

x86's memory model is basically program-order + a store buffer with store-to-load forwarding, so StoreLoad reordering is the only kind that can happen.

So yes, this is the closest you can come to ruling out `ra=rb=0` while still leaving a window open for it to happen.  Running on a strongly-ordered ISA (x86), with a barrier in one side.

It's also going to be really unlikely to observe when you only make one test per thread startup; not surprised it took you 30 minutes for these executions to happen at close enough to the same time across cores to observe this.  (Testing faster is non-trivial, like a 3rd thread that resets things between tests and wakes both other threads?
But doing something to make it more likely that both threads reach this code at the same time could help a lot, like maybe having them both spin-wait for the same variable, so they'd likely wake within a hundred cycles of each other.)

Answer (score 3):

Analyzing how the compiled code works is great if you want to know what happens at the hardware level and @petercordess has given a great answer (as usual).

But if you want to reason about the correctness of a program, you need to reason in terms of the Java Memory Model. Fences are not a [replacement](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-barriers-are-sane) for the JMM and fences only show you what happens at the hardware level; but not what happens at the compiler.

```
public class Main {
    public int a;
    public volatile int b;

    public void thread1(){
        a = 1;                  (1)
        int r1 = b;             (2)
    }

    public void thread2(){
        b = 1;                   (3)
        int r2 = a;              (4)
    }
```

There is a data race because if you would have the execution (1),(2),(3),(4) then r2 could be 1, but there is no happens-before edge since a (2),(3) doesn't provide one. There is no happens-before edge between a read followed by a write of the same volaile variable.

Since some executions can have a data race, r2 is allowed to read the initial value or a write it is in data race with; so a concurrent write. So that gives the values 0 and 1.

The JMM is happens-before consistent; so a read needs to see the most recent write before it in the happens-before order or a write it is racing with. This will prevent undefined behavior as you can get with e.g. C++ where any value can be returned.

Comment: I think the question was specifically whether you could still see this 0,0 result **in practice**, when testing on x86.  The OP later reported that they eventually did observe it after 30 minutes of testing (probably because most executions didn't run the two functions at close enough to the same time on different cores).  Your JMM analysis is also useful, as usual :)  But we can already infer that the JMM doesn't guarantee it, from the fact that it's possible in the x86 asm created by a presumably-non-buggy JVM.

Comment: But checking the standard is necessary to reason about UB, or Java's lack thereof, in case of a data race.  +1 for that alone.  Note that C++ undefined behaviour on a data race doesn't just mean "any value" can be returned, that would be an undefined *result*.  Undefined *behaviour* at any point in execution of C++ means that absolutely nothing is guaranteed about anything after, during, or even before the UB event.  In practice on HW without race-detection, you'd get asm like Java, but `clang -fsanitize=undefined` could abort instead of giving a 0 or 1 and still comply with ISO C++.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the heads up on the C++ clarification.

Comment: _But if you want to reason about the correctness of a program, you need to reason in terms of the Java Memory Model_. The reason for digging down to the machine code was that I was initially tried to prove using only JMM rules that reordering could not happen. When I failed the next step was to understand if it can happen on a specific arch in practice I was currently running on. Luckily it could be reproduced, but IMO it would be a much more difficult topic if it happened that on a specific arch reordering could not happen, but JMM would allow it on some other.

Comment: Reasoning what the hardware is doing will help to demonstrate that something is broken, but this technique can't be used to prove that the code is not broken. In this case, there is a missing happens-before edge between the write and the read, so you have a data race and hence the program is not correctly synchronized. Once you have determined that there is a data-race, it doesn't matter any longer what the hardware is doing.

Comment: It still is extremely interesting and informative to see what happens at the hardware level @SomeName.